# Transit Lines-Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

How can I use the transit lines layer using the Google Maps android API v2?

I've read and tested that if you use `setMapType` you can switch the map type with the options of `MAP_TYPE_HYBRID`, `MAP_TYPE_NORMAL`, `MAP_TYPE_NONE`, and `MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN`; and with another method called `setTrafficEnabled()` you can also turn on the traffic layer. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

seems its impossible, I'm looking also for that but can't find how to do it